# Axapta form input fields

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, ax

Is it possible to prevent axapta from remembering entered values in a form input field so that when the user has entered one value, they do not get a highlighted proposal for what they could enter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

1. Set the `AutoDeclaration` property of your control to *Yes*.
2. Execute `element.delAutoCompleteString(NameOfYourControl);` in one of your form's methods e.g. in `init`.